# How do you commit all files with one or more exception in git?

Tags: git, version-control

I am using git and generally I commit all of my changes using:

```
git commit -a
```

But this time I want to commit all my files except for one. The list of changed files is quite long so I don't want to manually commit them individually. I am looking for somthing of the format:

```
git commit -a -i ignore_this_file.c
```

Or somthing simple like this?

**EDIT:**
So I clone a git project. I modify 10 files. Then I only want to commit 9 files back in. However I still want to keep locally the modified 10th file for my local purposes (i.e. has some debug in it).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could add everything then remove the one you don't want to commit and then commit :

```
git add -u
git reset HEAD ignore_this_file.c
git commit
```

Comment: Thanks. Actually the file already exists (i.e. not added by me) but I have added some debug that I don't wish to commit back in. So I only need to do commit's not add's (if that makes sense)?

Comment: If you don't add the -a option to `git commit`, yet added files won't be automatically commited. That's why staging them for commit with `git add` then removing your file from the list of files to be commited (that's what the reset do) will do what you want.

Comment: If you do a `git status` after each step, this should be clear and you'll see what will be commited before you do it.

Comment: I am not sure I understand. It is clear to me, but I am just not sure how to do it (I added an EDIT to the main post to clarify)

Comment: Just do each instruction one after the other, and use git status to see what happens.

Comment: Ah, ok. It says "use git add <file> to update what will be committed". So `add -u` stages all the files for the commit. Then `git reset HEAD ignore_this_file.c` removes this from the staging and leaves the local copy un-changed? (just want to be clear on that last point before I do it! - i.e. my ignore file will be unchanged)

Comment: If you don't trust what says `git status` (or if you're not sure to understand it), you can also copy the whole repository and see what happens when you do all this.

Comment: Good point, I made a quick backup and messed around with it and works nicely, thankyou :)